# How do I remove the deploy key from the repository?

Tags: git, github

Trying to contribute to my first open-source project, followed the steps indicated in the [readme](https://github.com/TrackDons/trackdons), but the terminal outputs:

> trackdons git:(truncate-username) git push origin truncate-username
>   ERROR: Permission to TrackDons/trackdons.git denied to malditojavi.
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Looking for information on how to solve this, I found https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-to-user-repo-denied-to-user-other-repo/ where it states 'To fix this, remove the deploy key from the repository, and attach the key to your user account instead' . I have the correct key because if I do ssh -T git@github.com in the terminal I get the successful message:

> Hi myusername! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not
>   provide shell access.

Any idea how to remove the deploy key from my push, and include the right one?

Comment: Are you trying to push directly to the repository or to your own fork?